# System.EntryNotFoundException: Unable to find the entry point in the DLL

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, visual-c++

I am preparing a small C++ dll in which the functions are to be called from C#.

**DLLTestFile.h**

```
#ifdef DLLFUNCTIONEXPOSETEST_EXPORTS
#define DLLFUNCTIONEXPOSETEST_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLFUNCTIONEXPOSETEST_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" DLLFUNCTIONEXPOSETEST_API int fnSumofTwoDigits(int a, int b);
```

**DLLTestfile.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DLLFunctionExposeTest.h"
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    return TRUE;
}
DLLFUNCTIONEXPOSETEST_API int fnSumofTwoDigits(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

**C# project:**

```
static class TestImport
    {
        [DllImport("DLLFunctionExposeTest.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "fnSumofTwoDigits")]
        public static extern int fnSumofTwoDigits(int a, int b);
    }
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        int e = 3, f = 4;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            try
            {
            InitializeComponent();
            int g = TestImport.fnSumofTwoDigits(e, f);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the exception: "System.EntryNotFoundException: Unable to find the entry point in the DLL"

I am using the default template given by Visual Studio, when creating a new project, Visual C++ -> Win32 Project -> DLL (Export symbols checked). Can somebody please suggest the solution for this. I haven't been able to find the problem even after looking for long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me, complete files for reference:

dllmain.cpp:

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DLL.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    return TRUE;
}

DLL_API int fnSumofTwoDigits(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

DLL.h:

```
// The following ifdef block is the standard way of creating macros which make exporting 
// from a DLL simpler. All files within this DLL are compiled with the DLL_EXPORTS
// symbol defined on the command line. This symbol should not be defined on any project
// that uses this DLL. This way any other project whose source files include this file see 
// DLL_API functions as being imported from a DLL, whereas this DLL sees symbols
// defined with this macro as being exported.
#ifdef DLL_EXPORTS
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" DLL_API int fnSumofTwoDigits(int a, int b);
```

Program.cs (Win32 Console Application for simplicity):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("C:\\Users\\Kep\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\SODLL\\Debug\\DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "fnSumofTwoDigits")]
        public static extern int fnSumofTwoDigits(int a, int b);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int A = fnSumofTwoDigits(3, 4);
            Console.WriteLine("A = " + A);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still not able to find out what's missing in my file. Screenshot of caught exception: http://i.imgur.com/PJfxz.png

Comment: That's DllNotFoundException, use full path like I do for testing.

Comment: #FML. Yes!
P.S Where do you actually keep the DLL if that has to be done without the full path above?

Comment: In the same folder as the Application, for example. Or relative to that and use a relative path.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your C# process is running as 64-bits and your DLL is 32-bits or vice versa. I have seen this problem when the bit-ness of the processes and DLLs don't match.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't define DLLFUNCTIONEXPOSETEST_EXPORTS so you use the import declaration .  To test use dumpbin /exports to see what functions are exported from the dll.

Add

```
#define DLLFUNCTIONEXPOSETEST_EXPORTS 1 
#include DLLTestFile.h
```

Comment: DLLFUNCTIONEXPOSETEST_EXPORTS gets automatically defined by Visual Studio for the DLL Project. Just tested the above code and it worked fine.

Comment: Here is the screenshot of the Dumpbin.exe tool on my Dll. http://i.imgur.com/YXrvR.png

Comment: @ccKep: Worked fine? What about the entry point error that I am getting here?

Comment: Your names are mangled. which means there is somthing wrong with the extern "C" part

Comment: @rerun: His fnSumofTwoDigits isn't mangled as far as I can see?

Comment: @Cipher: Are you 100% sure you're using the correct path/version of your DLL?

Comment: Yea its not. You havn't changed the default calling convention in the c code did you to stdcall

Comment: @rerun: Visual Studio uses cdecl (which matches his import) as default for DLLs.